text box not showing up for the angular code
I am trying to learn angular code by converting the below react code into angular, however I am not able to see the text box in the browser an you let me know how to fix it.
React source

React Tutorial (youtube.com)

Angular code
With which I try to achieve what I saw in the react tutorial.

Playground (stackblitz.com)

<div class="user-search-container">
  <div class="user-search-input">
    <!-- pills -->
    <!-- input field -->
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        (input)="fetchUsers()"
        placeholder="search for a user..."
      />
      <ul class="suggestions-list">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Note how you have errors. You need to import the HTTP client service. The component loading is dying before the text-box is rendered because of that.

please check your console you have error "No provider for _HTTP Client!" you need to import httpClientModule in the component to use http client services i.e. making Api's calls

You have to provide HttpClient in appConfig file. I changed your example.
See the correct example here

thanks for your response, can you explain what changes you made...it is difficult to understand
